# Looping multiple arrays in HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

I am trying to create a loop in HAML that might use multiple arrays. Let me explain what I mean.

I have HAML code that looks like this:

```
- ['thumb1', 'thumb2', 'thumb3', 'thumb4'].each_with_index do |value, index| 
  - ['head1', 'head2', 'head3', 'head4'].each do |i|
    %span.span{:class => "photo-#{value}"} #{value} 
    %a #{i}ere
```

And it outputs to this:

```html
<span class='photo-thumb1 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head1</a>
<span class='photo-thumb1 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head2</a>
<span class='photo-thumb1 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head3</a>
<span class='photo-thumb1 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head4</a>
<span class='photo-thumb2 span'>thumb2</span>
<a>head1</a>
<span class='photo-thumb2 span'>thumb2</span>
<a>head2</a>
<span class='photo-thumb2 span'>thumb2</span>
<a>head3</a>
<span class='photo-thumb2 span'>thumb2</span>
<a>head4</a>
<span class='photo-thumb3 span'>thumb3</span>
<a>head1</a>
<span class='photo-thumb3 span'>thumb3</span>
<a>head2</a>
<span class='photo-thumb3 span'>thumb3</span>
<a>head3</a>
<span class='photo-thumb3 span'>thumb3</span>
<a>head4</a>
<span class='photo-thumb4 span'>thumb4</span>
<a>head1</a>
<span class='photo-thumb4 span'>thumb4</span>
<a>head2</a>
<span class='photo-thumb4 span'>thumb4</span>
<a>head3</a>
<span class='photo-thumb4 span'>thumb4</span>
```

But the output I really want is:

```html
<span class='photo-thumb1 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head1</a>
<span class='photo-thumb2 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head2</a>
<span class='photo-thumb3 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head3</a>
<span class='photo-thumb4 span'>thumb1</span>
<a>head4</a>
```

What am I missing here? If I try to erase the whitespace it would just throw an error.

Comment: Sorry @Alex, but is not clear what you want.

Comment: Do you really want the text to be `thumb1` for each of the spans in your output, or `thumb1`, `thumb2` etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your question is so confusing. It'd be something that you need?

```ruby
- [['tb1', 'hd1'], ['tb2', 'hd2'], ['tb3', 'hd4']].each do |thumb, head|
  %span{class: "photo-#{thumb} span"}= thumb
  %a= head
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But because I am trying to understand the process I would like ask you: What is the difference between .zip() method and the one you gave me. Thank you!

Comment: No difference, @Alex. This way is more didactic, `.zip()` will _convert_ into this structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you’re looking for is [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
- ['thumb1', 'thumb2', 'thumb3', 'thumb4'].zip(['head1', 'head2', 'head3', 'head4']) do |thumb, head|
  %span.span{:class => "photo-#{thumb}"}= thumb
  %a= head
```

Comment: Thank you so much, matt! I am sorry I put it in a very confusing way. It is hard to explain for me since I am new to it. The answer you gave me was exactly I had been looking for.